# Is there a way to use Glyphicons from Bootstrap 3 in the v2.x

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Is it possible to use the Glyphicons from Bootstrap 3 in Bootstrap 2.3.x ?

Problem is, i have a project with a old Bootstrap (2.3.2).

Since there were a major updates in BS3 with the grid system, i can't replace the bootstrap version so easy. It is very big project and to would take to much time to change it.

Actually everything works fine. Now my problem is, i am used to use BS3 and i also like the Glyphicons in there and now i thought i could may use them in my project.

Is there a "easy" way to do this ?

Comment: http://getbootstrap.com/customize/ Just get the bootstrap just with Glyphicon ?

Comment: Copy the fonts from the folder and then the CSS for the glyphicons/icon classes and do an override in your own separate CSS file.

Comment: You can get the glyphicons completely separately from Bootstrap here: http://glyphicons.com/

Comment: but than I have to write a whole new css so this is not a "easy" solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to GetBootstrap.com customizer. Toggle off everything except Glyphicons. Scroll down, there's more to not choose. Then get the css file from that download, remove all the base stuff such as normalize and the other stuff not related. Then create the fonts directory and make sure your site path matches the css follow the instructions on how to use on their site.

[image]

Comment: That is a LESS only solution.

Comment: This is css, it will spit out the CSS based on the Less variables that you include, so it's not ONLY it's both.

Comment: ill check this one and return for result